# Tuleap git pull request

Tags: git, tuleap, pull

In my Tuleap installation I don't see the Pull Request option with the git repository as mentioned in the user guide. what could be the problem ?

[No Pull Request Option beside git URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZVi4.png)

We don't want to use Gerrit, rather just Tuleap git tools are enough.[Tuleap Documentation for Pull Ruquests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1WdX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The *Pull Request* feature is provided via a plugin which seems not to be installed by default. You need to go in the Administration section and install then enable the *Pull request* plugin from the *Manage all plugins* tab.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it settled after installing the plugin.